# Is this use of the word "span" correct?

Tags: meaning

I know all the meanings of the word but i don't know how to use the noun in sentence. 
"You can't do a six years work span in one year" 
Is this sentence correct?
What i mean is that you cannot do six years worth work in one year.

Comment: You’ve got the noun there, not the verb. The new bridge will span the river just south of the city.

Comment: You are right, and i meant the noun . It has multiple meanings, i think it is clear which one i mean . Just want to check if this sentence is correct or not

Comment: Your *cannot do six years' worth work in one year* is idiomatically normal, but it's *not* natural to include the word ***span*** in such statements. I think it's for the same reason it would be "unnatural" to say *You can't pour a quart **volume** into a pint pot.*

Comment: But you might get away with, “You can’t do six years worth of work in the span of one year.”

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic phrase you are looking for is

> You can't do a six years *worth of work* in one year.

using *span* would not be appropriate in your sentence, if you used "in the span of one year" it would be understandable but redundant, or if you used "six year span of work" you would be referring to the *time span* of work, not the *amount* of work.